# Is there a way to utilize a old screen using electronics that can be handheld?

Tags: arduino, laptop, vga

So, I guess this is a follow-up question to my previous one: [Is there a way to output high quality pictures to a monitor with VGA using an Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558760/is-there-a-way-to-output-high-quality-pictures-to-a-monitor-with-vga-using-an-ar). Obviously, the answer did help me to get rid of the Arduino approach which would have cost both time and resources on my part (so thanks :)

But my question today is the following one: Suppose I have a laptop screen. I have its connector with it (it's with the screen). So, basically, it's just been disconnected from an old laptop from the 2009s. Is there a way to utilize it? I know I can use a PC to show pictures on there or, well, run windows. But is there something the size of an Arduino or something that can be handheld that will help me control the screen and input to it?

Edit: So, I don't know if this is a datasheet (I'm still a beginner in reading datasheets and patents per se), but this could be it: [15.4” WXGA+ TFT LCD](http://hands.com/%7Elkcl/eoma/laptop_15in/TFT-LED-LCD-PANEL-MODULE-NOTEBOOK-LG-15.4-LP154WP4-TLA1-1440-900-330-NITS.pdf)

Comment: Link to the datasheet for the screen or forget it if you don't have one, I reckon.

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, wait, editing in 10 minutes. Forgot about it, sorry...

Comment: @Transistor Ok edited it. Not really sure if this was what you needed though. My screen is a similar one, the link above is for one I found on the internet some hours ago.

Comment: Sure, if you have the screen datasheet, you can connect it to anything that outputs a picture with the same interface. It's just a matter of figuring out what the interface is and what devices will output a picture with the same inrerface, then connect them together and you are done. Now, there are many obstacles doing so, so in practice, if you are unable to find out enough info, then it is not possible.

Comment: *But is there something the size of an Arduino or something that can be handheld that will help me control the screen and input to it?* - I'm sure there will be something somewhere but asking for product recommendations is off-topic. Having uncovered a data sheet that is for a similar screen is like closing your eyes in a hardware shop and picking a tin of paint the has about the right size and hoping it matches the colour you ran out of when painting a wall.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, didn't know it was off-topic. Gonna flag it in a bit. Yeah, I'm kinda stuck cause I don't want to spend money on a tablet nor want to waste that screen. Anyways thanks!

Comment: Look at datasheets for (a) the monitor and (b) Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone or similar.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Okay, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop screens are usually custom manufactured for the likes of Dell and HP. Whilst they may use standard signals, you've got to figure out what they are and anything else in order to get it to work. Assuming the laptop is working, you can measure the voltages and observe the data to get an idea of what's what. Then you need to have hardware that can generate those same voltages and signals.

People have reverse engineered iPhone/iPod screens, so it can be done but it requires some skill and effort.

If you want a small system with a high resolution lcd, look at a tablet. You can find a myriad of no-name low cost Android tablets - I have a box of old tablets that I was given and not used. They are hi-tech waste :(

Learn how to write Android apps and you can have them do many useful things - even interface into Arduinos etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Yeah, I know how to write Android apps and actually, an UI was my end goal anyways. Just wanted to see if I could use it for making a simple photo slideshow. Anyways, thanks for the answer. +1 and selecting it